# Thymeleaf - rendering h tag with text

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying to render my variable inside an h tag.

I haven't seen any examples in the documentation suggesting how to do this.

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
<h1 th:text="${h1Var}"></h1>
```

I'm having to wrap my text with a span tag and using th:text within the span, is there any way around this?

Edit: working with 2.0.16

Comment: That's wierd because this should work. the th:text works with span, h, p,...

Comment: I've upgraded to 2.0.16 - and all it's working now.

Comment: @Chris you can add that as an answer and mark this question as answered.